# How to bind ScaleTransformation.X to slider in Silverlight 3

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I need to zoom Canvas. In WPF it is possible to bind ScaleTransformation.X to slider.Value.

I'm not able to do the same in Silverlight - some errors.

Is it supported in SL3?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code and the errors you're getting. Without these it's going to be hard for anyone to offer constructive advice.

Comment: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/126889.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is that in SL3 the binding target needs to be a `FrameworkElement`.  (This restriction is lifted in SL4 but that doesn't help right now).

However the solution just takes a little lateral thinking (or in this case backward thinking).  The source object does not need to be a Framework element.  So the answer is reverse the binding, that is put the binding on the `Slider` `Value` property and put it in to `TwoWay` mode.

```
<Border Width="200" Height="200">
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="TargetTransform" />
    </Border.RenderTransform>
    <!-- Some Content Here -->
</Border>

<Slider Value="{Binding ScaleX, ElementName=TargetTransform, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Width="200" Canvas.Top="250" 
    Minimum="0.1" Maximum="2.0" />
```