# Animation in Silverlight using a dynamic value

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation, keyframe

I want to translate an object on its Y-axis over time in Silverlight, but its height is not constant, so I'd like to be able to change the second line of the following from:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"  Value="-50"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.7000000" Value="0"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

to something more like:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"  Value="-100%"/>
```

or possibly:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"  Value="-{ExpandSite Height}"/>
```

That doesn't compile, however. I'd appreciate any help. I'm using Expression Blend 3, for reference.

**EDIT**

I basically want to achieve an effect similar to what's demonstrated [here](http://www.wynapse.com/Silverlight/Tutor/Clipping_Silverlight_Animated_Rectangles.aspx), but this code takes for granted that all the objects being translated are 100x100.

Comment: Its not clear what you expected your change to acheive?  What has the translation of an item in the Y direction got to do with its height?

Comment: I want it to start out translated up by its full height, and then dropping down by its full height. I updated my question with an example demonstrating what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/47930/127460.aspx) article describes that the keyframe element does not inherit from the framework element. Because of that you cannot databind to its properties and will have to do the changes in the code behind.

You can find an example of how to create code-behind animations [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/114854/262937.aspx). However, just note that there is an error in the sample code. The code is missing a line like `dd.KeyFrames.Add(easy)`. On the other hand, you can most probably access the animation if you give it an `x:Name` and just reference the array elements ( `animation.children[0].KeyFrames[0].Value` might work)

**EDIT**
I found another thread on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850380/how-to-bind-scaletransformation-x-to-slider-in-silverlight-3) site that does provide a possible work around for what you are trying to do, however I have not tried it myself.

Comment: How would I access the code behind a control I didn't create, but which I'm modifying via its template?

Comment: From what I've read, Silverlight 4 will have this restriction lifted and you will be able to use databinding for non-framework element objects, so modifying in template without code-behind in this case is not possible.